# How can I make a clickable link using an image derived from an individual element in an array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have two arrays. One array is a list of image file paths and the other is a list of image titles matched with the array of image files.The code generates a display of images accompanied by the appropriate image title.

What I want to be able to do is to select one of the displayed images which will then act as a link to a different page. I wish also to generate a session variable based on the file path of the clicked image.

I've researched quite a lot but am beginning to wonder if this can be done, or should I be working on a completely different approach. I am a beginner.
Here is my code.

```
    <ul>
    <?php
        foreach (array_combine($filepaths, $titles) as $filepath => $title) { ?>
            <li><img src=<?php echo "$filepath";? ></li>
            <li><?php echo $title; ?></li>
            <li></li>
    <?php }?>

    </ul>
```

Comment: `I wish also to generate a session variable based on the filepath of the clicked image`  PHP cannot detect clicks, as PHP is serverside and JS is clientside.   Basically clicks happen on a remote computer (the client) and PHP resides on the server.  So those clicks happen somewhere out in the internet.  You can do it, using Javascript and Ajax or submit a form (basically make a request back to the server) but it's too broad a topic for an easy answer.

Comment: What is the structure of the two arrays and why dont you use only one array for this?

Comment: @Bernhard - the structure is easy, see `array_combine($filepaths, $titles)`  One is `[filepath1,filepath2]` the other is `[title1,title2]`  combined they are `[filepath1 => title1]`  In the foreach the OP is using one array (created by combining the files with the titles)

Comment: If I can create a session variable from the individual array element, I can click on the div that contains an href, and this will take me to the new page, but I need the session variable to bring an identifier over to the new page or else the new page is useless. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix you are right. I need to get a coffee first :)

Comment: @OP does it need to be a session? because you can pass data to another page by using $_GET-parameters.

Comment: @Bernhard - there you go, I actually was going to mention that.  Because another side effect of using the session is that you can store only the data for one page.  Say a user has the page open in 2 tabs.  You would/could (infect/contaminate/poison) the second tab with the session data from the first one.  Depending on the particulars of this use case, that may or may not cause "strange" things to happen.

Comment: I did say I was a beginner. I mentioned the $title because that can be displayed alongside the image, so how would I go about sending a $_GET parameter?

Comment: You can send get by modifing the url `yoursite.com/page?date=somedata` the part after the `?` is the query string.  You can use `header('location: '.$url)` to direct them to that URL.  But there are some caveats with using header.  Any non-post request can be considered a get request, in general.

Comment: From javascript you can use `window.history.pushState(url)` but it doen't submit that to the server.  I know it's a pain...

Comment: Thanks to you both. Your comments have been very helpful. I'll investigate $_GET and see what I can work out. Any other thoughts are most welcome.

Comment: Youre welcome. BTW: because it has not been mentioned and you mentioned "link to a different page": A classic link would look like this: <a href="https ://example.com/?getparameter=value&othergetparameter=othervalue">link</a>. On the target page, you can read these parameters by using $_GET['getparameter'], $_GET['othergetparameter'].